# Get title of the latest record on a group

Tags: mysql, join

I'm doing a self join and I have the following query:

```
select 
    max( wf1.id ) as latest_id, 
    max( wf1.created ) as latest_created, 
    wf1.id, wf1.created, wf1.title,
    wf2.id, wf2.created, wf2.title
from
    worksheet_forms wf1
join
    worksheet_forms wf2
on
    max( wf1.id ) = wf2.id
where 
    wf1.company_id = '000002'
group by 
    wf1.generated_id
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
MySQL said: 

#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the title of the latest record of a group in the table.

EDIT:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id |   generated_id  |  company_id  |  title  |      created         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1  |  aaajdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws1   | 2012-02-08 17:27:30  |
|  2  |  aaajdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws2   | 2012-02-09 17:27:30  |
|  3  |  aaajdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws3   | 2012-02-10 17:27:30  |
|  4  |  bbbjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws4   | 2012-02-11 17:27:30  |
|  5  |  bbbjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws5   | 2012-02-12 17:27:30  |
|  6  |  bbbjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws6   | 2012-02-13 17:27:30  |
|  7  |  bbbjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws7   | 2012-02-14 17:27:30  |
|  8  |  cccjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws8   | 2012-02-15 17:27:30  |
|  9  |  cccjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws9   | 2012-02-16 17:27:30  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I want a result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id |   generated_id  |  company_id  |  title  |      created         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3  |  aaajdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws3   | 2012-02-10 17:27:30  |
|  7  |  bbbjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws7   | 2012-02-14 17:27:30  |
|  9  |  cccjdfie34343  |    000002    |   ws9   | 2012-02-16 17:27:30  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @MiD It would be easier to understand the problem if you post your current data and your expected result in a tabular format.

Comment: share your table data, then we can further help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your response guys! I updated my question with tabular data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, that's much simpler to understand. Running this:

```
select t1.* from t t1
left join t t2
on t1.generated_id = t2.generated_id and t1.created < t2.created
where t2.created is null
```

You'll get this:

```
+----+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
| ID | GENERATED_ID  | COMPANY_ID | TITLE |        CREATED        |
+----+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
|  3 | aaajdfie34343 |     000002 | ws3   |  2012-02-10 17:27:30  |
|  7 | bbbjdfie34343 |     000002 | ws7   |  2012-02-14 17:27:30  |
|  9 | cccjdfie34343 |     000002 | ws9   |  2012-02-16 17:27:30  |
+----+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Just select the fields you're interested in.